# hamgburgler.js links won't work on mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For some reason, I can click on the links on my computer but when I do it on a mobile device, the links don't work. I can't even click the X to close it again.

Can anyone figure out what the issue may be?

### [Here is a codepen](http://codepen.io/bgold/pen/oLzLJy)

### [View it on mobile](http://codepen.io/bgold/full/oLzLJy)

**HTML**

```
<div class="mobilenav" style="display: none;">
  <li><a href="/about.html">Story</a></li>
  <li><a href="background.html" class="cc-active">Accomplishments</a></li>
  <li><a href="experiences.html">Experiences</a></li>
  <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="icon">
  <div class="hamburger">
    <div class="menui top-menu"></div>
    <div class="menui mid-menu"></div>
    <div class="menui bottom-menu"></div>
  </div>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.bottom-animate, .top-animate {
    background: #1A936F !important;
    top: 13px !important
}

* {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: #1A936F;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent
}

.top-animate {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg)
}

.mid-animate {
    opacity: 0
}

.bottom-animate {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-225deg);
    transform: rotate(-225deg)
}

.bottom-menu, .mid-menu, .top-menu {
    width: 25px;
    height: 2px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #F9A530
}

.top-menu {
    top: 5px
}

.mid-menu {
    top: 13px
}

.bottom-menu {
    top: 21px
}

.menui {
    background: #1A936F;
    transition: .6s ease;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.75, 0, .29, 1.01);
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: absolute
}

.icon, .mobilenav {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed
}

.icon {
    display: block;
    padding: 9px;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    margin: 0
}

.mobilenav {
    font-family: inherit;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(200, 213, 185, .9)
}

.mobilenav li {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px
}

.mobilenav li a {
    font-size: 150%;
    color: #1A936F;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 300;
    width: 100%
}

.mobilenav li:first-child {
    margin-top: 60px
}
```

**JS**

```
function togglescroll() {
    $("body").on("touchstart", function(e) {
        if ($("body").hasClass("noscroll")) {
            e.preventDefault()
        }
    })
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    togglescroll();
    $(".icon").click(function() {
        $(".mobilenav").fadeToggle(500);
        $(".top-menu").toggleClass("top-animate");
        $("body").toggleClass("noscroll");
        $(".mid-menu").toggleClass("mid-animate");
        $(".bottom-menu").toggleClass("bottom-animate")
    })
});
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        $(".mobilenav").fadeOut(500);
        $(".top-menu").removeClass("top-animate");
        $("body").removeClass("noscroll");
        $(".mid-menu").removeClass("mid-animate");
        $(".bottom-menu").removeClass("bottom-animate")
    }
});
```

Comment: Seems to be working on my machine.

Comment: Yes but is it working on a mobile device? I've checked iPhone and android @jackfairfield

Comment: Oh yeah.... It doesn't work on I-phone.  Hmm.  Wonder why that would be.  I wonder if you are using something that isn't supported in safari

Comment: @jackfairfield it doesn't work on chrome or android phones either